# light box modal not working properly for images

Tags: php, html, css, image, lightbox

The following code is to retrieve 3 images and display in a table! i have imported the necessary jquery library and css script to implement the light box modal! but it does not work please help me! how do i need to corrrect the code?

```
        <?php
            require("includes/db.php");

            $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo"<head>";
echo"<link rel='stylesheet' href='image.css'>";
echo"</head>";

echo "<body bgcolor=#E6E6FA>";
echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 > " ;


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{


     echo"</td>";
     echo"<td align=center >";

   echo '<a href='.( $row['Image1'] ).'    >';
    echo "</a>";
   echo "<img id='myImg1' src='" .$row['Image1']. "' height='180' width='150'  />";



    echo "<br>";
     echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center >";


    if($row['Image2']=="No copy"){
        echo "No copy";
    }
    else{
     echo '<a href='.( $row['Image2'] ).'  >';
        echo "</a>";
   echo "<img id='myImg2' src='" . $row['Image2'] . "' height='180' width='150'  />";
    }



    echo "<br>";
     echo"</td>";
      echo"<td align=center >";

  if($row['Image3']=="No copy"){
        echo "No copy";
    }
    else{
     echo '<a href='.( $row['Image3'] ).'   >';
    echo '</a>';
   echo "<img id='myImg3' src='" . $row['Image3'] . "' height='180' width='150'  />";
    }



    echo "<br>";


     echo"</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>';

echo "<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its 'alt' text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg1');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img02');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its 'alt' text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg2');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img02');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its 'alt' text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg3');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('img02');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>";

   ?>
```

The relevant css file(image.css) is as follows

```
#myImg1 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg3 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg1:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
#myImg3:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;

    /** Unhide lightbox **/
    display: block;
}
```

currently the light box modal works for only the 1st row of images retrieved to the table but not for the rest? what is the reason ? how can i correct it?

Comment: check your IDs sometime they are `img02` and others `myImg2`

Comment: no those are 2 distinct ids 1 is for image and other for image content